# C# MVC, persist display only data to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, dialog

I'm currently trying to get server-side validation on a jquery modal dialog. I am submitting the form with Ajax and when validation fails, I want to to display the dialog and point out the validation errors.

I have most of it working, but there is just 1 issue I'm having.

The form is being submitted and is being received by the controller. It realizes that there are errors on the page and tries to redisplay the view. It cannot redisplay the view because it needs fields that weren't submitted, a table that only displays some data.

My question is, how can I get the view to submit a table that is holding model data.

For clarity, this is what is happening:

1.Modal dialog submit button pressed

2.Submits form data that is editable     <---- I want the non editable data to be submitted

3.Controller validates the model

4.Validation fails

5.Controller returns the model to the view

6.View can't display because some of the data is missing

This is the non editable data that I want to be submitted

```
@foreach (var hour in Model.Hours)
{
   <tr>
        <td>@hour.CreatedBy</td>
        <td>@hour.WorkingStart</td>
        <td>@hour.HourComment</td>
        <td>@hour.SecondsUsed</td>
   </tr>
}
```

The model:

```
public TaskEditAVwTask Task { get; set; }
public int numdays { get; set; }
public string firstday { get; set; }
public string lastday { get; set; }
public float taskhoursused { get; set; }

public List<TaskEditAVwHour> Hours { get; set; }
```

The main problem is that the view requires this data to redisplay itself.

I could just fetch the data from the database when validation fails, but I think this should be a last resort.

Sorry if this isn't very clear, I've tried to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working. This is what I did:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Hours.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.Hours[i].CreatedBy @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hours[i].CreatedBy)</td>
                    <td>@Model.Hours[i].WorkingStart @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hours[i].WorkingStart)</td>
                    <td>@Model.Hours[i].HourComment @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hours[i].HourComment)</td>
                    <td>@Model.Hours[i].SecondsUsed @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hours[i].SecondsUsed)</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Thanks to Ant P for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fetch them from the database again, why not just put them in hidden fields?

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyNonEditableField)
```

You can then simply ignore any changes to these values on the POST, to ensure nobody makes any sneaky changes to this data.

This is the canonical way to pass non-editable data through to a POST action. However, if this table is larger than you're letting on, there's really nothing wrong with fetching the data again.

Comment: One problem with this, and it's my fault for not telling you. The non editable fields are in a list that is being iterated, so that lambda won't work. I'll edit the OP for clarity. I'm sure there is a better way of displaying that table, but I'm still kinda new to MVC.

Comment: Html.Hidden(...) is passing the data to the controller, but with one problem. Multiple rows will have the same name attribute. Is it possible to submit the data as part of the model? I know that HiddenFor would set the name attribute as "ListName.MyNonEditableField". Would it be possible to do something like "List[0].NonEditableField"?

Comment: This shouldn't matter - as long as the fields have the same name attribute, the model binder should bind all of those fields to a `List<T>`.

Comment: Managed to get it working. +1 for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it correctly.
If you want to pass non-editable data through form, you can use :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NonEditableFieldToBePassed)
```

Comment: I think you understood it correctly. The problem is that the non editable fields are generated from a list, which means the lambda won't work. See edits to the OP and replies to the other answer for more details.